# Can oxidation of ethanol by copper(II) oxide yield copper(I) oxide as one of the products?

Tags: redox, transition-metals, alcohols

We know that ethanol is oxidised by copper(II) oxide to an aldehyde. Copper is reduced from $\ce{Cu^2+}$ to $\ce{Cu}$. Can this reaction, with some specific condition, yield $\ce{Cu2O}$ instead? That will also be a reduction of copper, only partial.

The [question was asked on a Russian chem forum](http://forum.xumuk.ru/index.php?showtopic=192917) and it made me curious.

Comment: If you add an excess of a reducing sugar to the mix, the copper(II) should all get reduced back to copper(I), i.e. Cu2O. I'm pretty sure that's not what you mean though ;)