# How to turn acetaldehyde into acetic acid using one of the five chemicals on the list?

Tags: reactivity

[From the Russian State Chemistry Test](https://ege.yandex.ru/chemistry/1/#question=17):

> [image]

It's easy to see $X$ is $\ce{H2O}$: water turns acetylene into acetaldehyde.

But what can turn acetaldehyde into acetic acid?

I checked: $\ce{NaOH}$ would turn it into sodium acetate, $\ce{CuO}$ would not react (you'd need $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$), ethanol would turn it into either an acetal or hemiacetal.

Would acetaldehyde react with formic acid to produce acetic acid? I tried to google for it, and found no mention.

Would water in the presence of a heat source somehow react with acetaldehyde? I googled and discovered that it might form hydrates, not acetic acid.

So I'm at a loss. If you consider the question too easy, you could give just a hint.

Comment: If you Google CuO oxidation of aldehydes you do get hits

Comment: I don't think it's a stretch to think that two copper(II) reagents would both do the trick, considering one is essentially just the hydrated form of the other...

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/can-oxidation-of-ethanol-by-copperii-oxide-yield-copperi-oxide-as-one-of-the

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxidation of aromatic aldehydes to acids by air oxidation catalysed by CuO is reported in Molecules 2008 13 948

None of the other reagents can oxidise aldehyde to acid.

Comment: Acetaldehyde isn't aromatic.

Comment: I know!! But given that CuO oxidises aromatic aldehydes it is not such a stretch to think it probably will oxide acetaldehyde. Plus none of the other options look even remotely right

Comment: [This paper says that acetaldehyde gives high yield of acetic anhydride when copper salts are used as catalyst](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/i260021a024).

Comment: Perhaps, but remember that we are supposed to solve the conceptual difficulties, not eliminate options like in a competitive examination. However I agree that $\ce{CuO}$ has a better chance of oxidizing.

Comment: A friend who teaches chemistry has just said to me that CuO will first turn into Cu(OH)2 and only then the reaction will proceed. I don't know whether that's true.